# Check which Bootstrap class is being applied and add behaviour according to that using AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, angularjs-directive

basically the issue that I'm experiencing is that I am applying two grid classes to an element like:

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
  <p class="text-style">Test</p>
</div>
```

and depending on if col-md-3 is applied or col-xs-12, change the behaviour of text-style, maybe I could do it only with CSS but anyway I'm using AngularJS to manage the app logic.

I'm using Angular 1.2 so also I could manage this within a directive but firstly, I would need to identify which class is being applied in each moment.

Answer (score 0):

Directive would indeed the right way, because Angular will pass it to the DOM it parsed. If you want to avoid it, you'll have to *read* the DOM without Angular like the jQuery way.

As you said, Angular can handle the logic of the app, therefore my recommendation would be let Angular handle both bootstrap classes applying and `text-style` behavior management.

Comment: But actually if I check in a directive the parameter 'element' or 'attrs' I can not find which class is being applied to the element between col-md-3 or col-xs-12 or how to get which one is working. For example if I open the browser console, I can see in each moment which class is working. So is there any tip I could follow to get this information ?? and based on that I could apply a certain behaviour the the <p> element.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have some condition to see which class to apply, can't you use the same condition to identify which class is applied? Or you can use [ngStyle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) to set the style accordingly.